# Opengl Selection Buffer

Tags: opengl, feedback, interaction

I'm using opengl's selection buffer, but i'm experiencing a trouble, the "picking" works perfectly if you hit the element for the first time, but the second time you hit it, it won't get selected, instead the element selected is an arbitrary one on the model. Any hints on this? Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that when I was picking on the polygon I wasn't careful enough to relabel it when changing the color, that's why it wasn't getting picked again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you, there is basic info and general approach about opengl picking: http://gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL:Tutorials:Picking

Another resource woulde be the OpenGL redbook (known as "the redbook")

For specific help I'd need to see some code and get some more information on your approach.